# what is difference between these two library and processsor directives?

Tags: c

what is the difference in working of these two directives?

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

and

```
#define pi 3.14
```

please explain what is the difference between these library and processor directives?

Comment: There's nothing at all similar about them. What's the difference between a car and an apple?

Comment: Cars are available in black and blue, apples are not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google slave request.

Answer (score 1):

The first one tells the compiler to include a header file.  The second one defines a constant "pi" that will get replaced everywhere in the code by "3.14" by the preprocessor.

[Read more about #define here](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php)

[Read more about #include here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html)

You should really try and do your homework yourself.

Comment: yes i know but really i cant differentiate about two different  things although i know about them... thanks by the way...